# when using entity framework model first, how to map string with different db types

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm, ef-model-first

for example:

```
public string Name { get; set;}
public string Comment { get; set;}
```

How to map Name with nvarchar(20) and map Comment with nvarchar(500)?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `Column`

attribute like this;

```
[Column(DbType="NVarChar(20)")]
public string Name { get; set;}
[Column(DbType="NVarChar(500) NOT NULL")]
public string Comment { get; set;}
```

[SQL-CLR Type Mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386947.aspx)